# Expanding textures in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, tile

I'm using libgdx to make simple tile based game and everything seemed to be fine, until I added a rectangle, which follows mouse position. I figure out, that whenever I jump, rectangle (and other blocks too) expands probably by 1 px, until I let the spacebar. When I hit the spacebar again, it gets to normal size. I tried printing out rectangle width and height, but they didn't change, so problem is with rendering.

[Everything allright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYM1U.png)
On this picture you can see game before jump.

[Wider textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqyuz.png)
Here is game after jump. You can also clearly see it on players head.

A little more detail. I don't use block2d. Tiles sizes are 8x8 scaled to 20x20. Using texturepacker without padding (problem occurs with padding anyway). I don't know which code to post, because I have no idea where the problem could be, so here is just simple block class. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
public class Block extends Sprite {

private int[] id = { 0, 0 };
public Rectangle rect;
private int textureSize = 8;

public Block(PlayScreen play,String texture, int x, int y, int[] id) {
    super(play.getAtlas().findRegion("terrain"));
    this.id = id;
    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, ID.tileSize, ID.tileSize);
    setRegion(id[0] * textureSize, id[1] * textureSize + 32, textureSize, textureSize);
    setBounds(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    draw(batch);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to libGDX!

TL;DR- there isn't enough of your code there to tell what the exact problem is, but my guess is that somewhere in your code you are confusing pixel-space with game-space.

### A Matter of Perspective

When you first create a libGDX game that is 2D, it's really tempting to think that you are just painting pixels onto the screen. After all, your screen is measured in pixels, your window is measured in pixels, and your texture is measured in pixels.

However, if you start looking closer at the API, you'll find weird little things such as your camera and sprite positions and sizes being measured as *floating point values* instead of integers (Why floats? You can't have a fraction of a pixel!).

The reason the dimensions of your game object are different than how big they are drawn. It's really easy to understand this in a 3D world- when I am close to something, it is drawn really big on the screen. When I am far away, it is drawn really small. The actual size of the object doesn't change based on my distance from it, but the *perceived* size did. This tells us that we can't safely measure things in our game just based on how they're drawn- we have to measure based on their **true size**.

As a side note, while you may be using an Orthographic camera (i.e. one without perspective) and drawing 2D sprites, libGDX is really drawing a flat 3D object (a plane) behind the scenes.

### Game Units

So how do we measure the "true size" of something? The answer is that we can measure it using whatever type of unit we want! We can say something is 3.5 meters long, or 42 bananas- whatever you want! For the sake of this conversation, I'm going to call these units "Game Units" (GU).

For your game, you might consider making each block one GU high and one GU wide (essentially measuring your game world in blocks). Your character can move in fractions of a block, but you measure speed in terms of "blocks per second." I can almost guarantee it will make your game logic a lot simpler.

### But our textures are in pixels!

As you probably already know, your game uses three things to render: A viewport (the patch of the screen where your game can be painted), A Camera (think of it like a real camera- you change the position and size of the lens to change how much of your world is 'in view'), and your game objects (the things you may or may not want to draw, depending on whether they're visible to the camera).

Now let's look at how they're measured:

- **Viewport:** This is a chunk of your screen (set to be the size of your game window), and as such is measured in pixels.
- **Camera:** The Camera is interesting, because its size and position are measured in Game Units, not pixels. Since the viewport uses the Camera to know what to paint on the screen, it does contain the mapping of GU to pixel.
- **Game Object:** This is measured in Game Units. It may have a texture measured in pixels, but that different than the "true size" of the game object.

Now libGDX defaults all of these sizes such that 1 GU == 1 Pixel, which misleads a lot of folks into thinking that everything is measured by pixels. Once you realize that this isn't really the case, there are some really cool implications.

### Really Cool Implications

The first implication is that even if my screen size changes, my camera size can stay the same. For example, if I have a small 800x600 pixel screen, I can set my camera size to 40x30. This maintains a nice aspect ratio, and allows me to draw 40x30 blocks on the screen.

If the screen size changes (say to 1440x900), my game will still show 40x30 blocks on the screen. They may look a little stretched if the aspect ratio changes, but libGDX has [special viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) that will counteract this for you. This makes it much easier to support your game on other monitors, other devices, or even just handling screen resizes.

The second cool implication is that you stop caring about texture sizes to a large degree. If you start telling libGDX "Hey, go draw this 32x32px sprite on this 1x1 GU object" instead of "Hey, go draw this 32x32px sprite" (notice the difference?) it means that changing texture sizes doesn't change how **big** the things on your screen are drawn, it changes how **detailed** they are. If you want to change how big they are drawn, you can change your camera size to 'zoom in.'

The third cool implication is that this makes your game logic a lot cleaner. For example you start thinking of speeds in "Game Units per second", not "Pixels per second". This means that changes in *drawing size* won't affect how fast things are in the game, and will save you a ton of bug-hunting further down the road. You also avoid a lot of the weird "My jump behaves differently when I resize the screen" bugs.

### Summary

I hope this is helpful and makes sense. It's difficult to get your mind around it at first, but it will make your life a lot easier and your game a lot better in the long run. If you'd like a better example with pictures, I recommend that you read [this article](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/) by one of the libGDX developers.

Comment: John, quit wasting time on StackOverflow and write a LibGDX book already! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for so detailed answer! First of all I used box2D (then I realized that it's not usefull for this type of game) and there I had to scale everything down by "pixels per meter" since box2D logic uses some kind of meters as unit and it didn't make much sense. But now I think, I understand it, so I'll somehow change the code and hope, it'll solve this problem. Thanks!